# can text be pasted in the Iframe of a aftereffects extension panel

Tags: javascript, html, after-effects, microsoft-forms

i have  aftereffects panel with a MS forms inside a iframe tag.i can write any text inside it, but i cannot copy any text and paste it inside the input tag of the iframe. any idea or a workaround?

Have tried creating a button to paste ,but iframe has cross-origin restriction.

to recreate my problem.Just create a iframe inside the after effects panel `<iframe       src="https://www.google.com/"       style="height: 600px; width: 500px"     ></iframe>` and try pasting inside the search bar.

Comment: Just so I'm sure I understand your problem - you have a text of some sort, and that text is outside of the iframe. Both the text, and the iframe are within AfterEffects. Your text is actual text, and not a text-layer. You want to select, copy, and then to paste that text into an input within your iframe. However, you're unable to do that. Is this correct?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @FiddlingAway hi the text is actually in clipboard.Its the comp name ,i have paste it inside the textarea of the Iframe.

Comment: to recreate my problem.Just create a iframe inside the after effects panel `<iframe
      src="https://www.google.com/"
      style="height: 600px; width: 500px"
    ></iframe>`    and try pasting inside the search bar.